# Set a starting value and count towards n and then back to the starting value

Tags: scheme

Basically I need to set a starting value (1) and count towards my n and back to one. And for each calculation I need to display the value.
This is what I have right now:

```
(define (teken-symbolen x y)
  (begin (display x) (display y) (display x)))


(define (teken-n x y n)
  (cond ((or(= n 0) (< n 0)) (display onmogelijk))
        ((= n 1) (teken-symbolen x y))
        (else (begin
                (teken-symbolen x y)
                (teken-n x y (- n 1))))))
```

What this does currently is display the value n only while I need to display every calculation from one towards my value n and back to one again all on a different line, which I figured I could use (newline) for.

Any help I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: If you are just displaying then print before and after recusive call and in the base case only print the value. If you want it to return a list then the simplest is to use `list` instead of display and `append` instead of `begin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what should happen when.. Eg. if you write

```
(begin (display 1)
       (display 2)
       (display 3))
```

In which order are the numbers displayed? So lets transform this to what you need to do. I have no idea why you think `x` and `y` are good values so I'm thinking you should have a contract.. Since you already know the first value (1) you only need `n` so I suggest:

```
(define (print-to-and-from n)
  ...)
```

Here are some expectations

```
(print-to-and-from 0) ; nothing printed (or whatever)
(print-to-and-from 1) ; 1 printed only once (perhaps)
(print-to-and-from 2) ; 1, 2, 1 printed
(print-to-and-from 3) ; 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 printed
```

You'll need to know that you are currently on `1` or `2` etc so you need a binding that is not part of the contract. This you can do with a helper.

```
(define (print-to-and-from n)
  (define (helper cur)
    ; In here you can compare cur to n
    ; and increase cur on consecutive calls
    ...)
  (helper 1))
```

Now if you looked at the outcomes from `2` and `3` in terms of relation to `2` and `3` you'll see that the second recursion of `(print-to-and-from 3)` is the same as `(print-to-and-from 2)`. Thus you'd like the default case to print before and after the next recursion so that you print `1`, then do the `2, 3, 2`, you get the control back and print `1` from the first step. Just like the first code in my anser except the second `display` is a call to the `helper`.

Also notice that when it stops it only prints the stop value once, even when it is `1`. Thus you base case should only print the current value.

**NB** It might be easier to make the helper a global variable. That is done with lambda lifting. eg. make all closure variables bound ones:

```
(define (print-to-and-from-helper cur n)
  ; In here you can compare cur to n
  ; and increase cur on consecutive calls
  ...)

(define (print-to-and-from n)
  (print-to-and-from-helper 1 n))
```

This doesn't change the program much except you need to write a little more. The advantage is that you can test the helper individually. Good luck!